# How to call a function when a @State variable changes

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a time selection subview with two wheel pickers, one for minutes and one for seconds. The values are bound to two (local) state variables in the parent view. I'm looking for a way to have a global state variable "time" changed every time when either one of the two local variables changes. I don't want to directly bind the two state variables for min/sec to the global state as I want only one variable there holding the time in seconds only. So there should be a conversion time = min * 60 + seconds.

I'm struggling to find a way of detecting a value change of the two local state variables.

Here's the subview:

```
struct TimePicker: View {
    var min: Binding<Int>
    var sec: Binding<Int>

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Spacer()
            Picker(selection: min, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach((0...9), id: \.self) { ix in
                    Text("\(ix)").tag(ix)
                }
            }.frame(width: 40).clipped().pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            Text("Min.")
            Picker(selection: sec, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach((0...59), id: \.self) { ix in
                    Text("\(ix)").tag(ix)
                }
            }.frame(width: 40).clipped().pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            Text("Sec.")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use combineLatest in the main view.

```
               struct MainTimeView: View{
            @State private var min : Int = 0
            @State private var sec : Int = 0

           @State private var myTime: Int = 0
             var body: some View {

                TimePicker(min: $min, sec: $sec).onReceive(Publishers.CombineLatest(Just(min), Just(sec))) {
                    self.myTime = $0 * 60 + $1
                    print(self.myTime)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to wrapped your global variable kinda

```
    class TimeObject : BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var time:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
  struct TimePicker: View {
    var min: Binding<Int>
    var sec: Binding<Int>
    @EnvironmentObject var time : TimeObject
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Spacer()
            Picker(selection: min, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach((0...9), id: \.self) { ix in
                    Text("\(ix)").tag(ix)
                }.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded(){
                        time.time = ix
                })
            }.frame(width: 40).clipped().pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            Text("Min.")
            Picker(selection: sec, label: EmptyView()) {
                ForEach((0...59), id: \.self) { ix in
                    Text("\(ix)").tag(ix)
                }.gesture(TapGesture().onEnded(){
                        time.time = ix
                })
            }.frame(width: 40).clipped().pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
            Text("Sec.")
            Spacer()
          }
       }
     }
```

...

```
TimePicker..environmentObject(TimeObject())
```

unfortunately don't have a chance to test